# Is there a way to make a program that runs on Java mobile phones using C++?

Tags: c++, c, qt, java-me, midp

I am using Qt/C++ for long time now, I am supposed to develop an application the will run on mobile phones (MIDP 1.0, and MIDP 2.0). I don't program with J2ME and learning it will consume so much time. So I was wondering is there any way that makes me develop such applications using Qt or at worst case any C/C++ framework.

Comment: I disagree. Learning a new language (that is quite similar to the one you know) is not that much time consuming... Is the amount of time the only reason?

Comment: Just make a C++ compiler that compiles to the JVM then port QT to it :)

Comment: @Burkhard: Yes, the amount of time is my main concern. Learning a language is not difficult but mastering it is very time consuming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, MIDP is a Java standard only, there is no way to run native C/C++ code on top of that virtual machine.

The phones run the Java virtual machine for a reason; bugs aside the programs run in a sandbox and cannot cause security problems with the phone itself.